# AngularJs component and padding

Tags: css, angularjs

I just created two dummy components in AngularJS 1.5 and I'm having an issue with my CSS. Basically, here is the output HTML:

```
<body>
    <app number="5" class="ng-isolate-scope"><div class="app__button___ngX_w">The value is 10</div></app>
    <price value="5" class="ng-isolate-scope"><span class="price__button___3-PzM">The price is 5€</span></price>    
</body>
```

The two classes defined on the "divs" look like this:

```
.app__button___ngX_w {
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border:1px solid #3e3e3e;
    background-color:#cecece;
}
```

The second one is the same, except the background color. However, the end result is quite unexpected:

[image]

After my investigations, I noticed that if I apply the classes to the surrounding component tag and change its "display" property to "block", it works.

However, I have no idea (and I'm not even sure it's possible) how to modify the class of the surrounding component tag, so my question is, what is the best way to avoid this to happen? Because it's quite a common scenario...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior corresponds to the html specification, since a `<span>` element is `display: inline` by default.

So you can achieve the desired result by either changing your css

```
.price__button___3-PzM {
  display: block;
  ... 
}
```

or by changing the `<span>` tag to `<div>`

[html fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vilsbole/tz2ph10c/2/)

[image]

Regarding **component reuse** with angular 1.5 you can either:

Rely on your bundler or es6 imports to limit the include the css with your component.

Or you may also imitate ng2.component syntax by defining your styles directly in the template declaration.

```
.component('price', {
       template: `
         <style>
           .price__button___uuid {
              background-color: teal;
           }
         </style>
         <div class='price__button___uuid> Hello </div>
       `
    })
```

[angular fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vilsbole/r15w491n/1/)

Comment: Ah! Thanks... That was a stupid mistake from me, the "span" was supposed to be a "div". Anyway, thanks for the more-than-complete answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It happens because unknown tags like `app` and `tags` are rendered as inline by default by browser. And then you have block level element inside of inline one - which is not allowed by spec and hence might be rendered unexpectedly.

You can fix it like this:

```css
app, tags {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this does not fix the issue. However, this is not a nice solution (no offense) because it means that the component cannot be used independently of the application. The goal is to have a component that you can drop wherever you want and behaves correctly (without being force to apply an external CSS)

Comment: @ssougnez while the idea of dropping a component in somewhere is nice, it still needs css and angular using non spec elements like app and tags, you need to take that into account. dfsq is correct

Comment: Well, I didn't say he wasn't right (I even upvoted the answer), I said that the solution was not optimal. Check at the accepted answer, you'll see that my code contained a stupid mistake; if the span is replaced by a div, the component behaves correctly and could be dropped almost everywhere (I guess there are some exceptions for complex CSS).